# IP Connflict on network

Tags: router

I keep getting an IP conflict on my home network and can't figure out why.

I'm running a Belkin-N wireless router that has an Ethernet connection to my 360 and a wireless connection running to my laptop.  It's WPA2 encryption and I have a nice password on my router consisting of letters , numbers and special characters.

But for some reason I keep getting IP conflicts at night time...By the time I look into the problem I don't see anyone else on the network.

Is my router giving me false positives?

Comment: Are you using DHCP or static IP addresses?

Comment: DHCP, but I haven't turned my laptop off in weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router should have a menu that lists all DHCP addresses currently assigned, and to what MAC address they are assigned to.

Likely you'll find that either your 360, laptop, printer, or other device is remembering an address that the router gave out long ago, and then gave out again to a device that rebooted.

Also check and see what address ranges are assigned to wired and wireless networks, and make sure they don't overlap.